# How to install wasabi wallet on armhf architecture

Tags: software-installation, deb, packaging, github

How to create and install [wasabi wallet](https://wasabiwallet.io/) on **armhf** architecture?

Is it possible to create it from its [GitHub](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/releases/) repository. If so, How?

Comment: You may try to compile from source according to their instructions but I have a feeling it won't work due to its heavy reliance in Microsoft products (.NET).

Comment: @ChanganAuto This is unlikely to even be possible. Because architecture is different. my architecture is 64